# New Spring Boot @EntityScan doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As of Spring ORM v1.4 `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan` was deprecated in favor of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan`.

I was going to remove deprecated annotation in favor of new one, but such replacement cause `IllegalStateException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:680) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
```

With `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan` annotation, application starts and works correctly.

Here is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.app.domain")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.app.persistence.jpa")
public class JpaInfrastructureConfig {
    // ... config props
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());

        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(new Properties() {{
            put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
            put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
            put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHbm2ddl);
        }});

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    // ...
  }
```

It seams that I've missed something, haven't I?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean that by removing `@EntityScan("com.app.domain")` you get the error message, right?

Comment: @user3590899 by replacing @EntityScan with new one, from ```org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan```

Comment: What if you remove the `@EntityScan` annotation and define at your configurartion file `JpaInfrastructureConfig`, `entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.app.domain"​)`?

Comment: @user3590899 well, it may work, but I want to make it work with annotation :)

Comment: The annotation doesn't do anything (nor does the old one) as you are using manual configuration and don't use spring boot auto configuration. So adding the annotation is pretty much going to do nothing. Why are you using manual configuration instead of using Spring Boot?

Comment: Thank you, @M.Deinum! That's why it's in **...autoconfigure...** package xD http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this issue on Spring Boot's issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6340), you'll find the behaviour changes with the new annotation, as now documented in the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4.0-RC1-Release-Notes#entityscan).

In your example, the simplest change would be to add a line to call `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(…​)`, as suggested in the release notes.